# Firefox print CSS - Extra blank page on A4 page

Tags: html, css, firefox, print-css

I created a simple print CSS which generates an A4 page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style media="print">
    * {margin:0;padding:0}
    @page {size: 297mm 210mm; margin:0mm;}
    html, body {width: 297mm; height: 210mm}
    html {background-color:red}
    body {background-color:green}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>TEST</p>
</body>
</html>
```

With Firefox 38.0.1, in the *Print Preview* window, the body (green colored) has an extra height which triggers a second page [image: firefox]

If I print the file, 2 pages are printed, so it is not a problem related only to the print preview.

I already removed all the margins from the *Page Setup* section and all the extra elements which Firefox adds (like title, url, date, ...)

The same page on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 does not have any problem [image: chrome]

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this, it will work straight forward :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media print {
                * {margin:0;padding:0}
                @page {size: A4 landscape; margin:0mm;}
                html, body {height: 100%;}
                html {background-color:red}
                body {background-color:green}
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>TEST</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DevilingMaster please accept this answer. This worked for me as well :)

Comment: Perfect, the only solution ever to work for me. Thank you

Comment: @julian-xhokaxhiu Thank you, saved me more headaches!